# capture div of an appended live html in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've appended the div in a previous function (contents depend on user entry). How do I get the contents of it? I'm using the correct selectors and .html() function in jQuery, but it does not see it. I'm looking for something of a .live() alternative, but not for events.

I've simplified the code, but you can get the jist of it from this.

here's the bit from the function which adds the content that I need:

```
$('#custom_order_options').html('<strong id="header_cpu">Intel:</strong>');
```

and here's the bit where I try to get the contents:

```
var header = $('#header_cpu').html();
```

header returns null.

Comment: If its in the DOM then you will be able to get that.

Comment: added some code and i've added the two functions in question here: http://pastebin.com/9cPAe8xJ
buttons function adds the content, getDefault function tries to get the content

Comment: if I print out the element with console.log($('#header_cpu')); I get all of it, but .html() returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you successfully add new elements into your DOM, you can query them.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/N9YAu/2/